# Элефанты и леонты и лесные сраки (Тредиаковский?)

Tags: поэзия

Уважаемые лингвисты!
Если вам не лень - попинайте меня по поводу вот этого **http://ritminme.ru/prymery/128-sraki** разбора известной пародии.
Особо - по комментариям к используемым в этом стишке словам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это пародия на теорию  трёх штилей, борьбу за чистоту русского языка.

Стрекочущу,ползущу,летящ, скачущ - не малоупотребляемые, а нарочито 
искажённые, неправильно образованные краткие формы от действительных
 причастий, тогда как краткие формы бывают только у страдательных причастий .

В зленем ,сраки,блате , грахе -неполногласные формы - не неупотребляемые,
 а невозможные  от русских нейтральных слов низкой тематики. Неполногласие - признак старославянизмов, использующихся только в высоком стиле, возвышенные слова.

А вот старославянизм "злак" использован рядом с низким "червец", ещё более сниженным чуждым ему суффиксом -ец (как стервец)
Урчит - почему  "Переносный смысл (журавль трещит)"? Нарочитое употребление низкого "урчит"(животный звук - урчит в животе или ворчит собака)вместо высокого "возносит,поёт". У журавля - ноги (как у человека, это фигура - персонификация)
Взрачно, превыспренно, преполезно - нарочитая возвышенность придаётся с помощью старославянских книжных приставок и корней.

Смачно - польское заимствование, низкий стиль.

Забываючи - суффикс -учи (-ючи) образует наречия от основ глаголов действия, а не мозговой деятельности(играючи, крадучись);

Элефанты , леонты,монты - нарочитое использование иностранных слов  с неясным для общей аудитории значением, у которых есть русские аналоги - намёк на борьбу с иностранными словами, портящими  русский язык.

Учиняют браки - использование несовместимости канцелярского "учиняют" и возвышенного старославянизма "брак", получилось как "учиняют драки".

Comment: Всё  понимаю, кроме первой фразы:
>Это пародия на теорию трёх штилей, борьбу за чистоту русского языка.  
  
При чем тут "теория трех стилей"?
Тем более "борьба за чистоту"

Comment: Может, коряво выразилась.Пародия  на Тредиаковского, а он  был в острой полемике с Ломоносовым и его теорией .Наиболее важными сторонами его жизни являются борьба за русский литературный язык и попытка реформы стихосложения. Он  настаивал на обогащении литературного словаря из языковой бытовой практики высших слоев общества,начал усиливать славянский элемент в своем литературном языке. Его переводы  изобилуют изысканными славянизмами, создавшими специфическую славу Т. как бездарному писателю, абсолютно лишенному языкового такта и вкуса.

Comment: Он стоял на точке зрения «научного перевода» - отсюда в пародии "монты", "элефанты".Тредиаковский был реформатором старого силлабического стиха и насадителем тонико-силлабической версификации.Он решил обновить традиционные размеры силлабического стихосложения (13-ти и 11-ти-сложник) путем введения постоянных ударений и цезуры - в пародии это тоже используется, от силлабической традиции у него сокращения слов, краткие формы.

Comment: @Людмила: Большое спасибо за столь подробный разбор, освещение ракурсов словообразования и словосочетания.

Answer (score 0):

Элефанты - слоны,  леонты, видимо, львы, сраки - сороки.

Что касается "известной" пародии, то как-то мне она на глаза попадалась, навсеидку - новодел, к Тредиаковскому отношения не имеющий.

Вот нашел ссылку, сам прочитал очень быстро, но похоже, что-то стоящее.
http://magazines.russ.ru/nz/1999/4/uspensk.html

Comment: Хм... Видно, ссылки, выделенной синеньким, мало.  
Дам в явном виде: http://ritminme.ru/prymery/128-sraki    
А Успенского я прочёл в первую очередь, спасибо.  
Мой интерес состоит в том, что я опубликовал ритмический разбор этого курьёза у себя на сайте. И туда стали ходить люди. Тогда я решил добавить ещё информации и сделать пословный разбор стиха. Естественно, в меру своего понимания. Но слов много - где-то ж и напортачил... help!